# eccentricity of a vertex in hypercube graph

Tags: graph-theory

I have a question in graph theory ,my question is: find the eccentricity of every vertex in hypercube graph?,I know that in $Q_(k)$ eccentricity of every vertex is $k$ but I can't prove it.I read in a book of graph theory this reason: since it takes $k$ steps to change all $k$ coordinates.but I can't understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi.
Suppose you are in $Q_k$. You know that $\{x,y\}\in E$ if $x_i=y_i$ for all values $i=1,\ldots ,k$ except for just one of them.
Recall that Eccentricity of a vertex $x$ is defined as $e(x)=\max_{y\in V} d(x,y)$ where $d(x,y)$ is the minimum distance between $x$ and $y$.

So you need to prove that $d(x,y)=|\{i: x_i\neq y_i\}|$ but $\forall x,y\in E$ you have that$\{i: x_i\neq y_i\}\subseteq \{1,2,\ldots, k\}$ then $d(x,y)\leq k$ and if you take $x\in E$, take $y=(1-x_1,1-x_2,\ldots,1-x_k)$ and you will have it.

In order to prove that $d(x,y)=|\{i: x_i\neq y_i\}|$ suppose $d(x,y)>|\{i: x_i\neq y_i\}|$ and suppose $d(x,y)<|\{i: x_i\neq y_i\}|$ and see what happens.

**Hint:** Try to arg in terms of the pidgeonhole principle.